# Is the word, “kinda-sorta” accepted as a normal word to be used in writing?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word, contemporary-english, register, literary-english

I was drawn to the word, “kinda, sorta” which appeared in the article of Time magazine (April 27) under the headline, “The Clippers Should Have Boycotted Game After Owner’s Racist Remarks”:

> The circumstances were unprecedented. The players, most of whom are
>   black, had to represent an owner whose allegedly racist views - the
>   team **kinda, sorta** questioned the authenticity of the audio - were now
>   broadcast to the world.
>
> http://time.com/78721/donald-sterling-los-angeles-clippers/

GoogleNgram shows that the “kinda-sorta”emerged around / in 1920, and its usage has been shooting up since 1980.

However, answers.yahoo.com says:

> "kinda-sorta" is not proper English. You shouldn't use it in any
>   essays or articles or anything proper that you might write. It will
>   make you sound unintelligent.

Is it too naive for me to presume that the word "kinda-sorta" is usable in (not-too-formal) writing as well as in speaking, now that I’ve seen the word being used in one of leading English language journals?

Comment: People say it, so it depends on what style of writing we’re talking about.  I wouldn’t use it in a peer-reviewed academic research paper; I might well use it in a piece of email.

Comment: Not necessarily relevant to the question, but I would never use _kinda-sorta_ at all: I would use _sorta-kinda_. I wonder if the order of the constituents in this compound is dialectal, sociolectal, idiolectal, or just completely random.

Comment: @Janus, I use both, but I think they mean different things. Not that I could articulate the difference to save my life, mind you.

Comment: I'm sorry you had no other responses. :( The question deserved other answers.

Comment: As @medica's good answer explains, this is quite a subtle issue. Let me just say that I think you are free to disregard any instruction that says anything as ridiculous as "[word] is not proper English. You shouldn't use it in any essays or articles or anything proper that you might write. It will make you sound unintelligent."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, that's a hard one. Not only are *kinda* and *sorta* both slang, and not often used in quality writing (unless to capture dialogue), this is a compound-slang word.

This is going to be an opinion-based answer, no mater who gives it. So I'll state mine.

I think for all but formal writing, it's fine. Most people will recognize the word as a humorous redundancy that quite captures the writer's (or his subject's) complex feelings.

New York Times bloggers have used it (blog in parentheses):

> - Pataki Kinda Sorta Not Running in ’08? (The Empire Zone)
> - ‘The Simpsons’ Explains Its Kinda-Sorta Feud With Fox News (ArtsBeat)

Other "good" blogsites (journalist, not personal):

> - Deep Ellum Is Kinda, Sorta, Maybe Back on Top! (Maybe.) (Dallas Observer)
> - Kinda Sorta Impeaching the President (Washingtom Post)
> - 9th Circuit to bloggers: You're all journalists now, kinda sorta (LA Times)

Answer (score 2):

No they should not have been used in that context - it is slang English; and as such only be used if being quoted as speech or if someone was writing an informal note to a friend.

If the article had quoted a player as saying "we kinda-sorta felt that we...." that would be acceptable as a direct quote.

To note normally newspapers/press articles are normally considered to be formal writing.